# Authentication is Required Google Play Store

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have tried everything that was said in the answers below but it just won't work. I want to download an application but whenever I accept the permissions prompt,  a notification appears: "Authentication is required. Please sign into your Google Account."

I don't know what to do anymore. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious? i.e., signing into your Google Account on your phone? If not, then what was the problem? You need to sign into your Google (GMail) account to download apps from the Play Store, it's a prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your Play Services data.

Go to Settings, Storage, Applictions, and look for Google Play Services. Delete data. Then, go back and scroll until the All tab. Look for Google Play Store. Delete data. Reboot. Enter credentials. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I logged out of Google and logged back in, and that fixed the issue for me.

The error may simply be a sign-in issue, which sometimes occurs when the Play Store is updated. The first trick is to go into your phone's main Settings menu and then Accounts & sync and simply remove the Google account that is getting the "authentication is required" error. Once you've done this, you can re-add the account and it should work just fine.

You can also restart your phone before re-adding just in case. However, you may need to do this step along with the second step below. I cut and pasted this from internet search maybe it will help you out. I don't take credit for this answer.